# Flutter - Creating a List variable from a JSON source

Tags: json, variables, dart, flutter

I'm trying to create a Variable List from the JSON source `crypoUrl` using the data from `_currencies.name` from the files `crypto_data.dart` and `crypto_data_prod.dart` from [this Git Repo](https://github.com/iampawan/CryptoApp).

If possible could you show me how to do this all in `home_page.dart`, then how to print the results to the debug terminal using something like `print(...);`

Thanks, Jake

Comment: It looks you are done with what you want. Can you please tell what you want in detail?

Comment: Sorry, instead of saying 'I'm figuring out' I should have said 'Im trying to create'. I've not made any progress on this yet

Comment: I looked into code. I am very sorry. Can you please  explain what problem you are facing?

Comment: When the app loads, a List in variable format needs to be created of the currency names as defined in 'crypto_data.dart' and 'crypto_data_prod.dart'. Thanks

Comment: Hey Dinesh, any luck with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cloned and ran your app. There was one compilation error in `crypto_data_prod.dart`.

If you are using **named import**, use like

```
import 'dart:convert' as JSON; // named import (importing convert lib as JSON)

final List responseBody = JSON.jsonDecode(response.body); // using with name
```

If you want without named import, then use like

```
import 'dart:convert'; // importing the lib without any name

final List responseBody = jsonDecode(response.body); // using the method directly
```

And after that i got this screen,

[image]

Do you want to solve somthing else?

Comment: Thanks Dinesh, this looks promising. I’ll get back to you about this in a few hours, I’m out at the moment

Comment: Thanks Dinesh, I now understand where the list is saved :)

Comment: Cool.. Happy coding